# What's the difference between coc-emmet and emmet.vim?

Tags: neovim, original-vim, plugin-emmet-vim

I'm working in HTML and want to choose emmet support for neo(vim) but don't know where to start.

What are the differences between `coc-emmet` or `emmet.vim`?

Answer (score 2):

`coc-emmet` provides completion support for `emmet.vim`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `emmet-ls` for getting completion feature for neovim.
You can use any package manager for installing the plugins.

you should also install html-lsp and css-lsp

[Neovim LSP](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lsp.html)
[LSP Config](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).